# What is "encountering local thread"?

Tags: openacc

In section 2.5.3 of OpenACC spec rev 2.5, it says "When an if clause appears, the compiler will generate two copies of the construct, one copy to execute on the accelerator and one copy to execute on the encountering local thread. What does this "encountering local thread" mean? Is it the CPU thread that invokes the GPU kernels? If so, the codes in the enclosing kernels construct will be executed on CPU, when the if clause evaluates to false?

Thanks for your help!
Peng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct and correct.  By "local thread" it's meaning the host thread.  If the if clause is false, then the region will run on the host, if true, then it will be run on the device.